# Controls de tag video não estão funcionando

Tags: html5, html5-video

Coloquei uma tag  e o atributo "controls" no meu html. A tela do vídeo aparece, e os controles também, porém nada acontece ao apertar os botões dos controles. Eu clico e eles nem dão sinal de que estão sendo clicados. A console do Google Chrome não retorna nenhum erro. O que pode ser? Segue abaixo o código:

```html
<video id="meuVideo" width="800" height="450" controls >
    <source scr="http://files.cod3r.com.br/curso-web/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

O erro está na escrita de "scr", o certo seria "src".

Comment: Nossa que vergonha. Eu olhei 300 vezes e não vi isso. Obrigado